# Evitar que me salga 0.00 en consulta SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo esta consulta y manda un datos 0.00 y no quiero que me muetre

mi query:

```
select
Descuento = isnull((
                SELECT sum(x.Valor)
                FROM Cuenta x
                where
                x.IdSer between 25 and 39
                and x.Valor != 0.00
                and x.IdA = cc.IdA),0)

from Cuenta cc

group by
cc.IdCur,
cc.IdAl
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mas alla que no se entiende la logica de este query, parece sobredimensionado, pq no podes usar un where para excluirlos?

Comment: Describe las columnas de tu tabla por favor, y muéstranos los datos de la tabla que resultan en este resultado.  El hecho que tengas un sub-select a la misma tabla `Cuenta` me indica que probablemente la consulta necesita ser restructurada.

Comment: esta consulta tiene varias subconsultas y el resto de datos me es imposible subirlas

Comment: Entonces simplifica el problema siguiendo los prinipios expuestos aquí: [mcve], para que podamos reproducir el problema y tener el cuadro completo.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya se menciona en los comentarios, das poca información y la consulta parece más compleja de lo que debería ser. Puntualmente para lo que preguntas, debes tener en cuenta que estás usando la función de agrupación *sum()*. En tu consulta, si tienes dos registros donde x.Valor es por ejemplo 5 y el otro es -5, la suma final de estos valores te dará un cero. Según se entiende con tu pregunta, quieres evitar los *resultados* que te den cero, no los registros individuales. Así que lo que podrías usar es una clausula [having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp):

```
SELECT sum(x.Valor)
FROM Cuenta x
where
x.IdSer between 25 and 39    
and x.IdA = cc.IdA
group by
cc.IdCur, cc.IdAl
having sum(x.Valor) != 0
```